# How to install the "Tree Ensemble Layer" on Kaggle Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip, kaggle

I would like to try the following code on Kaggle Notebook but I could not find a way to install the tf_trees.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tf_trees import TEL

tree_layer = TEL(output_logits_dim=2, trees_num=10, depth=3)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tree_layer)
```

It seems that tf_trees cannot be installed using !pip install

I would appreciate if someone could suggest a solution. Thank you.

Soruce: https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/tf_trees

Comment: Could you share why the installation methof mentioned on the github page you have linked does not work for you?

Comment: The problem is that the mentioned solutions on GitHub cannot be run on Kaggle Notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn on internet support first and clone the google-research repo from github:

```
!git clone https://github.com/google-research/google-research.git
```

then we need the compiling and linking options for g++ so run following code snippets:

```
import tensorflow as tf; 
print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))
```

and

```
import tensorflow as tf; 
print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))
```

for my notebook I got following flags:

```
-I/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
-L/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow -l:libtensorflow_framework.so.2
```

after that just replace the varialbes `${TF_CFLAGS[@]}` and `${TF_LFLAGS[@]}` with above outputs

```
!g++ -std=c++11 -shared google-research/tf_trees/neural_trees_ops.cc google-research/tf_trees/neural_trees_kernels.cc google-research/tf_trees/neural_trees_helpers.cc -o google-research/tf_trees/neural_trees_ops.so -fPIC -I/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -L/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow -l:libtensorflow_framework.so.2 -O2
```

at last we need to add system path

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/kaggle/working/google-research')
```

and run your snippet

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tf_trees import TEL

tree_layer = TEL(output_logits_dim=2, trees_num=10, depth=3)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tree_layer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is now working for me.